# How can I have end-users visualizing different dimensions from the same Powerpivot on same excel file?

Tags: permissions, security, excel-services, powerpivot, business-intelligence

[image]

I need help to understand if it is possible to have end-users visualizing different dimensions from the same excel file published in Sharepoint 2013.

I have a data warehouse in SQL Server 2012 and I am going to connect a Power Pivot/ Pivot Table to it.  The problem is, I have users who shouldn’t see some of the dimensions as they are for the top management only.
Can I restrict the data access of certain users so that they cannot see some of the dimensions on the PowerPivot of the excel file?

Should I use a dynamic security?
http://blogs.solidq.com/en/businessanalytics/getting-started-implementing-dynamic-security-row-filters-tabular-models/
If yes, I can I apply to groups (as configured in sharepoint). If not, is there an workaround?